# Building an algorithm that detects an area delimited by a quadrat

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, image-processing

I want to build an algorithm that takes an image and outputs the same image, but cropped so that it focuses only on a particular area delimited by a quadrat, like so:

[image]

This is not my image as I am not allowed to share my dataset. In my images, quadrats are made with different means (for example with wooden frame, or just measuring tape shaped to make a square).

I do not need a precise cropping. I just need the image to roughly follow the boundaries of the quadrat. But the difficulty comes from the fact that my dataset is heterogeneous and quadrats often not easy to see (they may be partially hidden by the grass, or have an approximative shape in the case of measuring tape).

My first idea was to build object detection algorithm and use the bounding boxes. I tried the one from LandingLens as a first try, which gave promising results, but I need to build one locally and have no idea which architecture they use. So I tried building a DETR network which does not seem to work. I also tried looking at deep learning based edge detection, which I might try but does not seem to be the perfect solution either.

Would you have suggestions or experiences about this particular type of task ?

Thank you